# netstat vs nmap to find IPs in a local network

Tags: routing, route, netstat, nmap

I'm in a local network : IPv4 shared address space (100.x.x.x). Connected to a wifi hotspot. Ip ranges : 100.76.164.0/23

When I run :

- `nmap 100.76.164.0/23` : It says all the hosts are down
- `netstat -rn` : it gives me a list of about 25 local ips (100.76.164.23, 100.76.164.27, etc)

Why can netstat -rn give me the IPs and not nmap? 
What's the difference between routing table and the nmap scans?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. Nmap is a tool that is mostly used to scan some specific ports. Netstat is mostly used to scan port mappings on your local machine. Also note, that Netstat was deprecated a long time ago, the replacement for it is "ss" tool. If you are just trying to scan your network, and ICMP traffic is permitted in your network, then I would use something more suitable for your purpose. Fping is a tool that can ping all hosts in the specified network and give you some stats in the end.

e.g. `fping -gs -r 0 100.76.164.0/23`
Where:
-s stands for statiscitcs in the end of the report
-g generate ips bases on network/mask
-r 0 (retry) only one ping retry per host

Please let me know if you need anything else.